# python / mysql - Transactions / Rollback not working

Tags: python, mysql, exception, transactions, rollback

First time using Transactions in MySQL

python 3.5.2

MySQL 5.7.16

SQL Alchemy

I have looked at other questions/examples but cannot figure out why the below code does not function as expected for me.

The second INSERT statement fails (intentionally for this example) and the exception handler should execute ROLLBACK. I would expect/desire the first INSERT statement to be removed from the database but it is still present.

Please could someone provide me with the correct solution.

```
def transaction():

    conn.execute("SET autocommit = 0;")
    conn.execute("START TRANSACTION")

    try:
        conn.execute("""INSERT INTO ....""")
        conn.execute("""INSERT INTO .....""") # this one fails 
    except:
        conn.execute("ROLLBACK")
        logging.warning('Exception SQL')
    else:
        conn.execute("COMMIT")
```

Comment: Are you seeing the `Exception SQL` warning?

Comment: 'Exception SQL' does populate in the Log file. (it was just something I was playing around with), so the ROLLBACK statement should be executed

Comment: Any reason you're not using the SQLAlchemy methods like `session.begin()`, `session.commit()`, and `session.rollback()`?

Comment: Barmar is correct, your connection tools handle the transactions and in fact, generally won't actually commit until told to (roll back is automatic). Get rid of any references to transactions in your execution -- use the tool.

Comment: in addition to the good advice from Barmar and SteveJ, also be sure the table we're inserting into is InnoDB and not MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use SQL Alchemy.

I tried the following code with "[mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/)".

```
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361342/python-mysql-transactions-rollback-not-working

python -m pip install mysql-connector-python
"""
import mysql.connector as m
import logging


def transaction():
    conn = m.connect(host="localhost", user="root",
                     password="", database="wpdc")
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SET autocommit = 0;")
        cursor.execute("START TRANSACTION")

        sql = "INSERT INTO wp_commentmeta (comment_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
        val = (100, "John", "John")
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        val = (101, "Foo", "Bar")
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
    except:
        cursor.execute("ROLLBACK")
        logging.warning('Exception SQL')
    else:
        cursor.execute("COMMIT")
        conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    transaction()
```

It worked.

[image]

I then removed the 2 rows from the database table and changed `val = (101, "Foo", "Bar")` to `val = (101, "Foo")` so that the 2nd `cursor.execute(sql, val)` would cause an exception.

[image]

The code worked as expected. The output was "WARNING:root:Exception SQL". No rows had been added to the database table.